# CSS transition doesnt hide the content

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a `div` where, on hover, I'm setting the height of the `div` to 0px. I have added a transition to the height property so the `div` looks like it is collapsing. However, the content of the `div` still displays.

*Note: I am using twitter bootstrap as well. If twitter-bootstrap already has something to show/hide with animation I don't mind using it.*

```css
.my-banner {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: rgba(104, 179, 212, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
     transition: height 1s;
}

.my-banner:hover {
    height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top tpt-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>            
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav tpt-navbar-links">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>                    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>                    
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu tpt-navbar-links">
                        <li><a href="/#/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-banner">
    <text>NOTICE: This is my banner.</text>
 </div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zoy4cuv/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `overflow: hidden` to the class `my-banner`. This will stop the `div` from showing content that falls outside of the elements area. Even when its height is `0`, that is not the same as `display: none`. Setting the `overflow` will fix that.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8zoy4cuv/3/

```
.my-banner {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: rgba(104, 179, 212, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
     transition: height 1s;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If element is top, bottom, right and left it works. What if element is center of page and want to hide? Overflow for right to left cuts text

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the `.mybanner` div shrinks in height, the cursor isn't over it anymore at a certain point (try to keep it up at the top, then it will hide almost completely). You can't hover something that is 0px high.

As an alternative, you could put the hover effect on the `<text>` tag inside `.mybanner`. At least on Firefox, that works (ie. havent't tried on other browsers):

```
.my-banner text:hover {
    height: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fjhqerdt/